# How to get text between two custom html tags in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I can get text between two custom html tags. Example:

```js
const a = "Hello, <num>22</num>";
//And here i want to get only 22 (between these two tags <num></num>
//I've tried something like this:
const nr = a.match(/<num>(.*?)<\/num>/g);
console.log(nr);
//But as you can see, it will only output <num>22</num>
```

Comment: To get the content of the first `num` tag, try `document.getElementsByTagName('num')[0].textContent`

Answer (score 6):

While you could just access the contents using something like [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), to answer your question from an input string via regular expression, you could use the [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function. This will return an array where the first element is the entire matched string `<num>22</num>`, and subsequent elements will correspond to the captured groups. So `nr[1]` will yield `22`.

```js
const a = "Hello, <num>22</num>";
const nr = /<num>(.*?)<\/num>/g.exec(a);
console.log(nr[1]);
```

Note that `exec()` is a function of RegExp, not String like `match()` is.

Comment: For additional reference for any readers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2647442

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the provided answers you could also add the string to a new element and search for it normally, for example

```js
const a = "Hello, <num>22</num>";
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.innerHTML = a;
var element = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("num")[0];
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

This allows you to match without actually inserting the text into the DOM and allows you to avoid regex which is not safe when parsing html.

Answer (score 1):

[It's generally not recommended to parse (x)html using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/769780).

Just a quick snippet here that works in Chrome, it looks like you can run queries against custom tags and also use the `textContent` property to get to the inner text:

```js
const customContent = document.querySelector('custom').textContent
console.log(`custom tag's content: ${ customContent }`)

const numContent = document.querySelector('num').textContent
console.log(`num tag's content: ${ numContent }`)
```

```html
<custom>inner text</custom>

<num>some more inner text</num>
```